# Offline Ready using Service worker

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, offlineapps, sw-precache

I built an offline first app using the appcache a while ago and wanted to convert it to using the service-worker (my clients all use the latest chrome so I don't have any browser compatibility issues).

I'm using sw-precache to generate a service-worker that caches my local assets (specifically, my html/css/fonts and also some js) and it looks like when the service-worker installs, it does successfully add all the assets to cache storage and it does successfully start (install and activate both fire and complete successfully.  And I have the self.skipWaiting() at the end of the install event to start the service-worker (which it does successfully as well)).

The issue is that the "fetch" event doesn't seem to ever fire.  As such, if I go offline or open a browser (while already offline) and navigate to the site, I get the Chrome offline dinosaur.  When I look at the network tab, it looks like the browser is trying to hit a server to retrieve the pages.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I didn't touch the fetch method that was generated by the sw-precache utility...so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My fetch event is below:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
     var urlWithoutIgnoredParameters = stripIgnoredUrlParameters(event.request.url,
  IgnoreUrlParametersMatching);

var cacheName = AbsoluteUrlToCacheName[urlWithoutIgnoredParameters];
var directoryIndex = 'index.html';
if (!cacheName && directoryIndex) {
  urlWithoutIgnoredParameters = addDirectoryIndex(urlWithoutIgnoredParameters, directoryIndex);
  cacheName = AbsoluteUrlToCacheName[urlWithoutIgnoredParameters];
}

var navigateFallback = '';
// Ideally, this would check for event.request.mode === 'navigate', but that is not widely
// supported yet:
// https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=540967
// https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209081
if (!cacheName && navigateFallback && event.request.headers.has('accept') &&
    event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html') &&
    /* eslint-disable quotes, comma-spacing */
    isPathWhitelisted([], event.request.url)) {
    /* eslint-enable quotes, comma-spacing */
  var navigateFallbackUrl = new URL(navigateFallback, self.location);
  cacheName = AbsoluteUrlToCacheName[navigateFallbackUrl.toString()];
}

if (cacheName) {
  event.respondWith(
    // Rely on the fact that each cache we manage should only have one entry, and return that.
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.keys().then(function(keys) {
        return cache.match(keys[0]).then(function(response) {
          if (response) {
            return response;
          }
          // If for some reason the response was deleted from the cache,
          // raise and exception and fall back to the fetch() triggered in the catch().
          throw Error('The cache ' + cacheName + ' is empty.');
        });
      });
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.warn('Couldn\'t serve response for "%s" from cache: %O', event.request.url, e);
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
}
```

}
});